# java move a shape object

Tags: java

i have a program that create the circle that move to random position with multithread, each thread will handle each circle movement. i know how to move a image but not a shape object.

g2d.draw(s.circle);

this line only paint the circle with spawn x y.

i've tried add 
s.circle.getBounds().setLocation(s.x, s.y);
before 
g2d.draw(s.circle);
but no effect

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (draw == true) {


        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

            for (Star s : this.items) {
                //g2d.drawImage(s.starImage, s.x, s.y, this);

                g2d.draw(s.circle);

            }

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();

    }
}

public void run() {

    //if (!items.isEmpty()) {
        while(true){
            try {
                for (Star s : this.items) {
                    s.move();
                }
                repaint();

                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Board.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    //}
}
```

Comment: And what happened? BTW, I don't think you need a thread for a single shape.

Comment: one click one circle one movement

Comment: I knew it buddy, I have done an app like yours, and it ran on a single thread.

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to

```
1) draw the circle
2) wait for some short interval (eg, 100ms)
3) REDRAW the same circle - This time with the background colour, so that it has the effect of erasing the shape.
4) draw the circle at the new location.
5) repeat.
```

Atleast the above worked for me when I was doing Java/2D - sorry for not posting the actual code, as it was long ago - but I'm sure you'll figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the screen, then painting it again. Use double-buffering to prevent flickering.